# Laravel foreach each item increment by 3

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I don't really know the title of this one and tried searching but I don't have any idea on what keywords should I put it on so I create a new one but if there is already a similar post to this. Can you link it? My question is how do I achieve this goal in the image below.

[image]

```
@php $i = 0; @endphp
@foreach ($posts as $key => $post)
 @if ($key % 2 === 0)
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"><img src="{{ $post->image }}" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    - {{ $i+=1 }}
    - {{ $i+=2 }}
    - {{ $i+=3 }}
   </div>
  </div>
 @else
 @endif
@endforeach
```

The alternate class from bootstrap is working but the numbers that would increment on each value is I don't have any idea on how to get it done.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, this is just bad approach. Views are for displaying stuff and using @php is just for extreme cases. Pre-compute the numbers ahead in controller and just display them. Either way, could you please share bigger picture I fail to understand what you are trying to approach.

Comment: @Kyslik on the image provided, each row has each detail including images. the numbers on each side are just an ordinary number but counts by 3. So the first row from array will display the number as 1, 2 and 3, then the 2nd row from array will continue the number from the first row which is 4, 5 and 6 and so on. Do you get what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Larval syntax, but for the logic I think you should have something more like this:

```
@php $i = 0; @endphp
@foreach ($posts as $key => $post)
 @if ($key % 2 === 0)
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"><img src="{{ $post->image }}" /></div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    - {{ ++$i }}
    - {{ ++$i }}
    - {{ ++$i }}
   </div>
  </div>
 @else
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8">
    - {{ ++$i }}
    - {{ ++$i }}
    - {{ ++$i }}
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><img src="{{ $post->image }}" /></div>
  </div>
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Things to note that I changed:
1. Increment `$i` by one for EACH number, otherwise you'll be skipping numbers
2. When `$key` is NOT event, print the image on the other side.

Again, I'm not familiar with larval syntax, and I also don't know what the key/values of your `$posts` array are (if your keys aren't alternating even/odd you won't have the images back-and-forth between left-and-right).

Hopefully this gives you some direction though.

Comment: Ah, I get your point and thank you for this, it is completely working fine. Thank you very much! Edit: For some reason, I can't accept your answer within a minute. I'll just wait for a minute to accept it :) thanks

Comment: Side comment: if `$key` is not part of asociated array but numeric one (in collection it would be the case for instance), you can avoid initialization of variable `$i` and use `$key + 1`.